# Why is the .Count of a List<T>(Int32) with initial size 0?

Tags: c#, list

Hi today I stumbled over a thing with the `List<T>(Int32)`. I thought the behaviour would be the same in following examples:

1.

```
var myList = new List<string>(5);
myList[1] = string.Empty;
```

2.

```
var myArray= new string[5];
myArray[1] = string.Empty;
```

The first example fails and I get a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'. The second example works well.

So I tried `.Count` on the list and it says its 0, where as when I put `.Length` at the array it says 5.

In MSDN it says:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that is empty and has
>   the specified initial capacity.

I thought this means the list has the initial size I pass in. Why isn't this the case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: End user behavior would be ~same for Dictionary instead of List. [Also be aware of how capacity changes by default](https://ideone.com/tRawzz).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial capacity refers to the internal array storage maintained by the list.

If you expect to hold 100 items and you specify 100 as initial capacity, you avoid the overhead of the internal resizing of the array (well, actually the list avoids creating a new array and copy the values from the previous one...).

Maybe now you've realized that a list (and many other collection types) are just an abstraction of arrays to provide specific semantics: lists, sets, dictionaries...

For example, a list collection with `100` items of initial capacity might add items to an internal array which already has `100` indexes/slots:

```
int[] array1 = new int[100];
array1[0] = 1;
// until...
array1[99] = 2;
```

...while a one which doesn't provide a *good* capacity, it may need to internally handle the insertion of 100 items this way:

```
int[] array2 = new int[3];
array2[0] = 1;
array2[1] = 2;
array2[2] = 3;

int[] array3 = new int[6];
array2.CopyTo(array3);
array3[3] = 4;
array3[4] = 5;
array3[5] = 6;

int[] array4 = new int[9];
array3.CopyTo(array4);
array4[6] = 7;
array4[7] = 8;
array4[8] = 9;
// and so on...
```

The whole internal array as list's storage already does a minimum reservation, but this is just an implementation detail. If you already know how many items you're going to add to the list, it'll be better that you provide an initial capacity.

Note that the initial capacity doesn't fix the maximum capacity of the whole list. This would defeat the purpose and semantics of lists: a collection of objects ordered by *inserting order* (FIFO, *first-in, first-out*). Once the capacity has been reached, the internal array is resized again.

Also, since lists in the higher-level are described as just object collections, you can't expect that providing an initial capacity could provide access to the internal storage indexes. The fact that there's an internal array storing collection's object is an implementation detail, you need to rely on high-level details:

```
// Above reason is why you CAN'T access myList[1]
var myList = new List<string>(5);
myList[1] = string.Empty;
```

### Further details

Hopefully, now most .NET Framework source code is available online. You can take a look at `List<T>` source code to check yourself how it works internally:

- [`List<T>` source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

Answer (score 10):

[Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) is how much elements actually in the list, [Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) is the size of the internal data structure. It's intended to handle large list that you already know the size beforehand, so it doesn't need repeated resizing when adding.

Comment: It should be noted that since Capacity is "the number of elements that the List<T> can contain before resizing is required," the List is still not a fixed size. Exceeding the Capacity of the List will create a new internal array and copy over the information,  whereas an array is a fixed size.